# How to "loop" through dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a query with a nested query inside of a where condition.

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table
WHERE create_date = date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)
and id NOT IN (
              SELECT DISTINCT id 
              FROM some_table 
              WHERE date_trunc('month', current_timestamp)
              )
```

This query gets the metric for this month. However, what if I want it for *all* months?

I tried this query, although it doesn't seem to run/takes a very long time:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', t.create_date), COUNT(id)
FROM table t
WHERE id NOT IN (
              SELECT DISTINCT id 
              FROM some_table tt
              WHERE date_trunc('month', tt.create_date)= date_trunc('month', t.create_date)
              )
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', t.create_date)
```

I would like to execute this command via Postgres CLI (from the command line).

Any guidance to make this query more efficient or logical appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the execution plan to your question?

Comment: @Andreas Added detail about command line, if that was what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for explain output: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html

Comment: Try to change `not in` to `not exists` condition.

Comment: @Abelisto Decent suggestion, although it returned zero rows -_-

Comment: It is about the query speed, not about data. Usually `not exists` works faster then `not in`.

Comment: You show a presumed solution. But you forgot the exact definition of the task, and basic information about your environment - like exact table definitions. [More instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info). There are elements in your query that might not do what you expect, but we can't say for sure, since we don't know what you are trying to achieve exactly. That's like saying: "Is 42 a  good answer?" One might base [a whole trilogy of five books on this funny approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HG2G).

Comment: You are using month, but for all months it means year. instead of date_trunc('month', current_timestamp) use to_char( current_timestamp, 'YYYY') to compare year.